# Is it possible to handle a detailed search filter as a GET request instead of POST request?

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, post, get, webapi

I write an API for report fetching with detailed filters, such as filters for recordIds, userIds, tagIds, basically multiple different id lists are part of the filter.

So far I coded these fetches as POST requests with id lists in body but I got curious if it is possible to handle these filters as a GET request instead?

What I searched so far yielded that, it doesn't seem possible since there is multiple List based filters and request is likely too big to be a GET but still, I'm curious if there is possible work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is according to your requirement.

If you are using post, you could post a complex object inside the body and this request will be more security than the get method.

If you wan to use get method, you could put all the parameter inside the url. Each url will contains the limit and build the complex object in the url is not recommended. If this also match your production environment, you could modify the codes to use get method.